# Getting CPU Usage from linux server in python

Tags: linux, python-3.x

So I connected to my vps trough python and when I want to get CPU Usage from server I get CPU usage from my PC

```
shell = spur.SshShell(hostname="ip", username="root", password="password", missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
        psutil.cpu_percent(interval=5, percpu=True)
        print(psutil.cpu_percent())
```

Can someone help ? Thanks !

Comment: how is this question any different than the other question you asked?

Comment: Guy told me to search for psutil and I did, I explained in this topic what is happening now. I wanted to lock that other topic that I posted but dont know how.